# Contact form php script sending spam to Gmail

Tags: php, forms, gmail, contacts, spam

I created a php script (for a contact form) to send emails to my Gmail account.
If I use the sender email in the header (**$headers = "From: " . $email;**), Gmail reports the received message as spam.
If I don't use the email in the header (e.g. the sender name **$headers = "From: " . $name;**) the message is not reported as spam.
Do you have any suggestion to let me use the email in the header?
Thanks!

```
<?php

/* Check if the url field is empty (antispam) */
if ($_POST['leaveblank'] != '' or $_POST['dontchange'] != 'http://') {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $faillink = "xxx.php";
    header("Location: $faillink");
} else {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject_prefix = "[ContactForm]: ";
    $subject = $subject_prefix . $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $to = "myemail@gmail.com";

    $body = "From: " . $name . "\n";
    $body .= "Email: " . $email . "\n";
    $body .= "Message: " . $message . "\n";

    $headers = "From: " . $email;

    $oklink = "yyy.php";
    $faillink = "xxx.php";

    if ( preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $name ) || preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $email ) ) {
        header("Location: $faillink");
    }

    $retmail = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    if ($retmail) {
        header("Location: $oklink");
    } else {
        header("Location: $faillink");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: This is common procedure. Whoever uses that contact form could choose whatever sender email he likes. Since GMail has no way to verify that it was actually the owner of that adress it is flagged as spam.

Comment: You should really only use contact forms like this to send mail to yourself and don't care whether it is spam or not, in which case you can set up a filter in your inbox to accept these to bypass your spam filter.

Comment: Set the **From** address as `noreply@yourdomain.com` and then set **Reply To** as `$email`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue as [Iain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2601598/iain) suggested so I replaced the mail headers as follows:

```
$headers = "From: " . "noreplay@mydomain.com" . "\r\n";
$headres .= "Reply-To: " . $email . "\r\n";
```

Comment: In addition to setting the sender address in the headers, as you've done above, you may also want to the set the envelope sender address as well.  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php for more info.